# Sort tuples by one of their elements in haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, tuples, element

I have a list like this

```
[(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)]
```

And I want to sort it by the second element, so it'd be:

```
[(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)]
```

I've tried

```
mySort t = sortBy (compare `on` (\(a,b)->b)) t
```

But ghci does not recognice sortBy apparently

Okay, editing:

I'm using GHCi to compile actual .hs files, so i've got my header:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

module TupleListPolynomial where
type Poly = [(Float,Int)]
```

And if I write it like this, the compiler won't recognize 'module'(using :l and :r btw) :

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TupleListPolynomial.hs, interpreted )

TupleListPolynomial.hs:5:1: parse error on input ‘module’
```

And if I flip it and write the imports below it won't recognize 'import' with the same error.

EDIT: Solved by putting it like this:

```
module TupleListPolynomial where
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
type Poly = [(Float,Int)]
```

Comment: forgot `import Data.List (sortBy)`? (before you ask: `import Data.Function (on)` too ;)  - ah yes and you have to do something about *descending* - *hint*: you can use `flip compare`)

Comment: Also, you can replace `\(a,b)->b` with `snd`

Comment: You need to use backquotes (\`) around `on`, not regular apostrophes.

Comment: ok - for the last part: you have to put the `import` parts after the `module` parts

Comment: just one simple advice/observation: I guess the `Int` part here is for your exponents - but you can represent a polynomial simply by listing it's coefficients so `a_0 * X^0 + a_1 * X^1 + ... + a_n * X^n` can simply be represented by `[a_0,a_1,...,a_n]` - this way you will not have to sort any thing and you could write `newtype Poly = P [float]` (or make it even more generic with `newtype Poly a = P [a]` using `Num a => ...` for your operations on the polynomial) - the newtype is there because I think you will soon make it an instance of `Num` ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few observations:

- to get `sortBy` and `on` you have to import them first
- you want to sort in descending order and one way to do this is to use `flip compare` instead of `compare`
- instead of `\ (a,b) -> b` you can also use `snd` (thanks Arnon)
- you have to use back-ticks `` ` `` instead of `'` for `` `on` `` (thanks interjay)
- the `t` in `mySort t = ... t` is not needed

### one possible solution:

ok - this one should compile and also load and works into ghci if you put it into some `myPolynomial.hs` file (or however you want to call it):

```
module TupleListPolynomial where

import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

type Poly = [(Float,Int)]

mySort :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
mySort = sortBy (flip compare `on` snd)
```

### in GHCi you would write

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

let mySort = sortBy (flip compare `on` snd)
```

indeed this is what I did to test it like this:

#### test

```
> mySort [(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)]
[(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)]
```

Comment: Hey thanks but, I've got this in the header

    module TupleListPolynomial where
    type Poly = [(Float,Int)]
    import Data.List (sortBy)
    import Data.Function (on)

And the compiler doesnt recognize the import D:
Can't format sorry

Comment: well you probably have to repeat it in GHCi ;) (really hard to tell without seeing your actual code and what you really did)

Comment: btw: the imports usually come before any definition (maybe you can add your actual code and your compiler-errors) - but the part I wrote under *in GHCi you would write` works for me and they should really work for you too

Comment: Uh, i've edited main post for more insight and actual explanation of the compiling error

Comment: @dari1495 I left you an comment there - I will also edit my answer for this

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by putting the imports between module and  type, apparently if I put module after type, it won't recognize it

Comment: yes the order is quite fixed - you will usually do: extensions -> module -> imports -> now you are free ;)